# Using getline to read text by passing in smart pointer argument

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Smart Pointers can usually be used in all places raw pointers are used (or so i've been told). Let's say I allocate an array of 256 characters and read in a line of text using `std::cin.getline()`

```
char* text { new char[256] };
auto smart_text { std::make_unique<char[]>(256) };

std::cin.getline(text, 256); // legal
std::cin.getline(smart_text, 256); // illegal
```

My question is esentially why I can't use `smart_text` the same way I use `text`. Both are pointers to a character array but they are simply managed differently.

My guess is that the smart pointer is an abstraction from the STL and `std::getline` is legacy code that only accepts a raw pointer argument. In this case, would the following be the "right way" to approach the problem?

```
std::cin.getline(smart_text.get(), 256);
```

In which case we're simply passing in the memory address of the pointer underneath the abstraction?

Comment: `getline` wants exactly a `char *`, so yes, yes, and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is esentially why I can't use `smart_text` the same way I use `text`.

Because smart pointers don't have *implicit* conversions to raw pointers. To pass a smart pointer where a raw pointer is used, you need an *explicit* conversion to access the raw pointer that the smart pointer is holding.

> My guess is that the smart pointer is an abstraction from the STL and std::getline is legacy code that only accepts a raw pointer argument.

Yes <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1. The STL is now known as the "standard library", and you mean `std::istream::getline()` instead of `std::getline()`, neither of which are legacy.</sup>

> In this case, would the following be the "right way" to approach the problem?
>
> ```
> std::cin.getline(smart_text.get(), 256);
> ```

Yes.

> In which case we're simply passing in the memory address of the pointer underneath the abstraction?

Yes.